# Joining fields with long field attribute names

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, length

I am working with the "Joins" option in QGIS 3.10, which joins the fields from two attribute tables based on a common shared attribute column.

However, this does not work for attribute values with a large length.

E.g. the following field **value** can be joined:
2404252385

While this one cannot:
551482643342511892418838370

I checked carefully if it may be due to other problems, but it clearly seems to be the problem of the number of characters. For example, I can filter both features by the attribute fields, which returns the respective row. However, the joined fields nevertheless show 'NULL', i.e. the common field name could not be found.

Can somebody confirm this problem and is there maybe a workaround/solution to fix this?

Edit: I am referring to field values, not field names. I tested around and possible issues that might be the problem are:

- The columns that I want to join are both called "fid"
- The columns that I want to join are of type string, not integer

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to clarify if "2404252385" and "551482643342511892418838370" are field *names* or field *values*. If they're *names*, you really ought to prefix them with a character (a-z), so that they're *legal* names.

Comment: Fixed this to refer to field values. I also edited the post, to provide more information what I found out could be an issue

Answer (score 3):

Fieldnames of shapefiles are limited to 10 characters. You can use another file-format like Geopackage to bypass this issue.

Comment: Will geopackage support all-numeric column names?

Comment: Valid question. I am not sure about official specifications, but did a quick test and its working fine. However need to figure this out at docs.

Comment: Trying to use the Geopackage file format did not resolve the issue, but then it was also meant to bypass the issue of fieldname character size. I clarified above that I have the problem specifically due to the fieldvalue character size.

Comment: It was about how I originally understood your question, so about length of fieldnames. But you can also use longer fieldvalues in geopackage than in shapefiles. How did you specify the field? Name, Type and length of its content?

Comment: The long (27-character size) fieldvalues are also displayed in the shapefile-format. The fieldname is 'fid', the type is QString/string, and the length is 50

Comment: I would still appreciate any advice from anyone. Could not resolve this issue so far. (don't know how to push this topic further atop to reach some more people...)